# Создание background для элемента программно

Tags: java, android, background, design

Есть задача создать такой backfround для элемента, чтобы там был stroke с градиентом, а также был закругленные края у этого элемента. Делать это нужно программно, так как цвет градиента будет меняться.

Как можно это сделать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        <gradient
            android:angle="360"
            android:startColor="#543456"
            android:endColor="#ff00b5"
            android:type="linear" />
        <size android:width="24dp"
            android:height="24dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот  [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453478/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-create-a-drawable-and-assign-it-to-an-imagevi)

Comment: @РусланЯгупов Я посмотрел, но вопрос так и решило, потому что этот градиент делается на всю площадь, а мне нужно только вокруг моего элемента в форме линии

Comment: Если не сможете без хака найти способ, тогда сделайте обычный градиент и вложите элемент в контейнер, и установите контейнеру бэк ему с padding толщиной которой нужна для вида градиент.

Comment: Можете дизайн элемента добавить для ясности?

Comment: @РусланЯгупов Добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал вьюху для примера:

```
public class StackGradientView extends LinearLayout {

public StackGradientView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public StackGradientView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public StackGradientView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setBackground(generateCoolDrawable(new int[]{Color.parseColor("#543456"), Color.parseColor("#ff00b5")}));
}

private Drawable generateCoolDrawable(int[] startEndGradient) {
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
            startEndGradient);
    gd.setCornerRadius(20f);

    GradientDrawable rectangle = new GradientDrawable();
    rectangle.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    rectangle.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[]{
            gd,
            rectangle
    };

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 40, 40, 40, 40);

    return layerDrawable;
}

public void changeColor() {
    setBackground(generateCoolDrawable(new int[]{Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#ff00cc")}));
}
}
```

Переделайте размеры чтобы из dp to px конвертировались.

[image: Сначала]

[image: Смена динамически]